# android sdk google play service last update

Tags: java, android, google-play-services

how i can download last version google play service sdk android without sdkmanager and google site ?

Update google playe service for resolve this problem :

> Error:Failed to resolve: com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:12.0.+

I need direct link download last version google play service sdk.

Answer (score 0):

You can download the Google Play SDK from the [Google Play Games Services documentation](https://developers.google.com/games/services/downloads/sdks). SDK's available for iOS, Android and C++.